# HTML form POST method pass "+" as %2B, "=" as %3D. How can I get original "+" and "=" sign?

Tags: html, forms, http, post, encode

I am writing a **web server** that can handle the data passed from **HTML form** using POST method.

I typed `c=a+b` in the form and submit the form(click "run" button). It looks like:[HTML page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pi6Tq.png)

The server got the body of the POST request. Its body looks like this:

```
code=c%3Da%2Bb
```

[the console of server side shows the content of POST request including header and body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLG2l.png)

"c%3Da%2Bb" is encoded. I have to use some functions to replace `%3D` to `+` and `%2B` to `=`.

I am looking for some ways that I can get the original text in textarea("c=a+b") instead of encoded text("c%3Da%2Bb").

I tried to change the "Content-Type" from "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" to "text/plain" by add "enctype" in my HTML form:
'''

'''
It actually helps me get the original text("c=a+b") in my server:
[the last line is body of POST request and it is the original text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsVPG.png)

But someone said changing to "text/plain" is not a good way.
So is there a way I can get the original text directly instead of decoding data on my server side.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Can you add a failure message? Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Please try to provide [mcve].

Comment: Your `<form>` encoding type (`enctype`) should typically be `multipart/form-data` so: `<form enctype='multipart/form-data' ...>` should resolve your issues with PHP `$_POST` elements. (or maybe I misunderstand your specific question context?)

Comment: @Martin — It won't. multipart/form-data is rather more complex to parse than application/x-www-form-urlencoded data.

Comment: @Quentin I think I am misunderstanding the question. I thought that OP wanted an input of `c=a+b` (in a form field) to be read as `c=a+b` in PHP at the other end.

Comment: @Martin – That was my reading of the question too, but they seem to be reading the raw request body, and a raw multipart body is more complex than a raw urlencoded body. (And if they use `$_POST` it can handle _both_ formats transparently).

Answer (score 0):

That's the way this media type ("application/x-www-form-urlencoded") works. A blank space is represented by "+", so "+" needs to be encoded differently.